# Is there a way to get out of the LAN mode in single player? and if so how?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to keep the commands off for my video's and I accidentally started LAN mode in single player and I'm not sure how to set it back to normal if it's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can close then reopen the world to turn off LAN.

Comment: Is there a command also?

Comment: @RobertLane Not yet! (In 1.11.2)

Comment: I also try to desactivate the LAN, read your your answer, but can't figure out what you mean by "close" a world

Comment: @lordbyron press the escape key then press "save and quit to title."